# JavaFX Chart axis label formatting

Tags: java, charts, javafx, label, linechart

I wrote a simple program to monitor my ping. I'm currently using `NumberAxis` with auto ranging, and after each ping, I add the new data at the end, remove the first one and increment `totalCount` variable for X axis position.

I would like the X axis label to either:

- show time elapsed since start. So for example, the label for 1100th ping at 0.25s ping intervals would be `4m 35s`
- show time since the ping. This would require the labels to remain static (not move with the plot) and be in reversed order.

Is either of these two (preferably 1st) possible to implement? I suppose I would have to use `CategoryAxis` for this, but I'm not sure how to create unlimited number of categories and choose to show only full minutes. Is it possible to keep the `NumberAxis` for easier use with incoming data and just change the label text formatting? I already have a method that converts seconds to `00h 00m 00s` format.

Also another thing, I think related to auto ranging, the chart doesn't refresh after every input, but only once it exceeds 10% of given range. So for 1000 range as in the picture, it will draw 100 new pings, and then move everything 100 positions to the left. Can I change it somehow to move after just 1 ping?

[image: ping]

Not sure if relevant, but I'll post the code:

Controller

```
public class GuiController implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button startButton, stopButton;
@FXML
TextField sField, nField, ipField;
@FXML
LineChart<Integer, Integer> chart;
@FXML
Label timeLabel, pingLabel;

ScheduledService<Integer> scheduler;
ObservableList<Data<Integer, Integer>> data;
public static int totalCount = 0;

private String getTime(double seconds) {
    int h = (int) (seconds / 3600);
    int m = (int) ((seconds % 3600) / 60);
    int s = (int) (seconds % 60);
    return String.format("%dh %dm %ds", h, m, s);
}

public void start() {
    if (sField.getText().isEmpty() || Double.parseDouble(sField.getText()) == 0)
        sField.setText("0.1");
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    int size = Integer.parseInt(nField.getText());
    stop = false;
    flip();
    XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> series = new Series<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(totalCount++, 0));
    }
    chart.getData().clear();
    chart.getData().add(series);
    scheduler.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(Double.parseDouble(sField.getText())));
    scheduler.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            if (series.getData().size() >= size)
                series.getData().remove(0);
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(totalCount++, scheduler.getValue()));
            updatePingLabel(scheduler.getValue());
        }
    });
    scheduler.restart();
}

public void stop() {
    scheduler.cancel();
    stop = true;
    flip();
    totalCount = 0;
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    return str.matches("?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}

public void flip() {
    ipField.setDisable(!ipField.isDisabled());
    nField.setDisable(!nField.isDisabled());
    sField.setDisable(!sField.isDisabled());
    startButton.setDisable(!startButton.isDisabled());
    stopButton.setDisable(!stopButton.isDisabled());
}

public void updatePingLabel(int ping) {
    pingLabel.setText(ping + "ms");
    if (ping < 80)
        pingLabel.setTextFill(Color.LAWNGREEN);
    if (ping >= 80 && ping < 150)
        pingLabel.setTextFill(Color.GOLD);
    if (ping >=150 && ping < 400)
        pingLabel.setTextFill(Color.ORANGE);
    if (ping >= 400)
        pingLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    stopButton.setDisable(true);
    chart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    sField.textProperty().addListener(new ParamsChangeListener());
    nField.textProperty().addListener(new ParamsChangeListener());
    scheduler = new ScheduledService<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
            return new PingTask(ipField.getText());
        }
    };
}

class ParamsChangeListener implements ChangeListener<String> {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue,
            String newValue) {
        if (isNumeric(newValue))
            timeLabel.setText(getTime(Double.parseDouble(sField.getText())
                    * Integer.parseInt(nField.getText())));
    }
}
}
```

Ping Task

```
public class PingTask extends Task<Integer> {

int time;

String address;

public PingTask(String text) {
    address = text;
}

@Override
protected Integer call() throws Exception {
    try {
        String cmd = "";
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
            cmd = "ping -n 1 " + address;
        } else {
            cmd = "ping -c 1 " + address;
        }
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        while ((inputLine != null)) {
            if (inputLine.startsWith("Reply from")) {
                String[] parts = inputLine.split("[ =ms]");
                time = Integer.parseInt(parts[9]);
                break;
            }
            inputLine = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return time;
}
}
```

FXML

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GuiController">
<center>
  <LineChart fx:id="chart" alternativeRowFillVisible="false" animated="false" createSymbols="false" horizontalZeroLineVisible="false" legendVisible="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" verticalGridLinesVisible="false" verticalZeroLineVisible="false" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <xAxis>
      <NumberAxis animated="false" forceZeroInRange="false" minorTickCount="0" minorTickLength="0.0" minorTickVisible="false" side="BOTTOM" tickMarkVisible="false" tickUnit="1.0" upperBound="200.0" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis animated="false" autoRanging="false" forceZeroInRange="true" minorTickCount="0" minorTickLength="0.0" minorTickVisible="false" side="LEFT" tickLabelGap="5.0" tickUnit="20.0" />
    </yAxis>
  </LineChart>
</center>
<left>
  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <children>
              <Label text="IP " />
              <TextField fx:id="ipField" prefWidth="100.0" text="euw.leagueoflegends.com">
                 <opaqueInsets>
                    <Insets />
                 </opaqueInsets>
              </TextField>
           </children>
           <padding>
              <Insets top="5.0" />
           </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <children>
              <Label text="Ping co " />
              <TextField fx:id="sField" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefWidth="60.0" text="0.25" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets right="5.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </TextField>
              <Label text="s" />
           </children>
           <padding>
              <Insets top="5.0" />
           </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
           <children>
              <Label text="Rysuj " />
              <TextField fx:id="nField" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="60.0" text="1000" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
              <Label text=" próbek" />
           </children>
           <padding>
              <Insets top="5.0" />
           </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <children>
              <Label text="Pokaż  " />
              <Label fx:id="timeLabel" text="0h 4m 10s" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <children>
              <Button fx:id="startButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#start" prefWidth="50.0" text="Start" />
              <Button fx:id="stopButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stop" prefWidth="50.0" text="Stop" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <Label fx:id="pingLabel" text="0ms" textAlignment="CENTER">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="40.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
     </children>
     <padding>
        <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
     </padding>
  </VBox>
 </left>
 </BorderPane>
```

---

EDIT

I tried using the formatter, but I'm getting `ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` at application.GuiController$XAxisLabelConverter.toString(GuiController.java:1) and I don't know what to do with it.

```
    class XAxisLabelConverter extends StringConverter<Integer> {

    double interval;
    int n;

    public XAxisLabelConverter(double interval, int n) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Integer value) {
        if (value < n) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return getTime(value.intValue() * interval);
        }
    }

}
```

In the `start()` method

```
    ((ValueAxis<Integer>) chart.getXAxis()).setTickLabelFormatter(new XAxisLabelConverter(
            Double.parseDouble(sField.getText()),size));
```

Comment: To converge to MCVE you could also post the fxml.

Comment: @UlukBiy added FXML.

Comment: You keep trying to change narrow the definition of NumberAxis.  The declaration is `public final class NumberAxis extends ValueAxis<Number> ` .  I'm no expert on types, but I think it's better to just use Number and get the intValue().

Comment: Your types are completely messed up. Since your FXML is creating `NumberAxis` instances as the axes, and `NumberAxis extends ValueAxis<Number> extends Axis<Number>`, you *must* make your chart a `LineChart<Number, Number>`. Then you need `XYChart.Series<Number, Number>` and `XYChart.Data<Number, Number>`, and finally you need to define a `StringConverter<Number>` as the formatter. As @brian says, you can call `intValue()` on any `Number` instance, so you really lose nothing by doing this. The only other way is to implement `ValueAxis<Integer>` youself, and you don't want to do that...

Comment: Or, just `@FXML`-inject the axis directly: `@FXML private NumberAxis xAxis ;` and `<NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" .../>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a [formatter to a number axis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#setTickLabelFormatter-javafx.util.StringConverter-).

You may just want to remove the x-axis.  It doesn't really add any information.  If you're just showing the last 100 pings which were .25 secs apart, then you don't really need an axis to know when they happened.

The chart is only moving after 100 pings due to the range of the axis.  The interval will depend on the total range.  The only way to change this is to shut off auto-ranging and set max, min, size yourself.  You could use this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#NumberAxis-java.lang.String-double-double-double-).

If you want to format you'll need a specialized converter since you need to modify the number.  The Chart<..,Number> needs to convert a Number to a String so use a `StringConverter<Number>`,eg.

```
    xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            return (object.intValue() * 0.25) + "s";
        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

ps. I've only used this on windows but you can see if it performs better than a new process.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)

Comment: That sounds like an FXML issue.   I never liked using FXML for charts, it seemed problematic at the time.  Show how you declared the axis and chart in the FXML.

Comment: Previous comment was my bad, don't know if you read that in time. 
Initially I had the x axis removed, but with different range and intervals, it was unclear how long my ping spikes were. Sometimes I'm showing last minute and sometimes its one hour.

Comment: @brian I added FXML to the post.

Comment: If you're still having trouble casting, use James_D's solution of putting an fx:id on NumberAxis.  Maybe the declaration in the controller should be LineChart<Number,Number>

Comment: I am having trouble using the formatter. I added some code at the end of my question.

Comment: Do you know how to change the range to move after every ping? I tried `((NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis()).setUpperBound(totalCount);
    ((NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis()).setLowerBound(totalCount - size);` but it's not enough, it still moves only for once every 10% range

Comment: Did you set autoranging false?

Comment: I figured already, I had to change the tick size too, but after I did I was unhappy with the result, it was inconsistent because I had to calculate the labels to show manually (to show only 10 labels but keep the tick size to 1) so I reverted back to auto-ranging for now

Comment: I would just get rid of the axis.  It doesn't convey the information you want.  If you want to know the range is 10 minutes, put a big "last 10 min. ping times" title.